# How to access view models and models of project in another class library without adding reference to the class library

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a WPF project using MVVM pattern. In solution, I have viewmodels,models,views and properties.As per requirment, I need to access the same classes(view models, models, properties) from another class library in same project. I do not want to add the reference to the class library as it is an exe file and a heavy component which has got so many classes which i do not require. So, is there any solution for this. How can i access same classes(view model,model,propeties) in a solution from another class library in same project?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: "from another class library in same project" - do you mean in the same _solution_?

Comment: yes from same solution. @Sam

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices. First one, is to refactor your exe in order to extract the reusable classes to a separate dll. Then, just add a reference to this new dll.

The other is to use reflection to access the members of the exe, which is the worst option, even worse than simply adding a reference to the big old exe.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest breaking down your solution further in more projects, For example separate projects for Model, View and ViewModel or perhaps breaking down even further and then add reference only to the library you need. That way you are not exposing everything.

The other option is reflection which may be cumbersome to use and make your code ugly.